# Как создать суперпользователя в терминале с ключом ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

```py
class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Worker(AbstractUser):
    position = models.ForeignKey(
        Position,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="workers",
    )
```

Есть модель пользователя, у которой одно поле это `ForeignKey` на модель `Position`. Хочу создать суперпользователя, чтобы быстро заполнить БД для тестов. В терминале `python manage.py createsuperuser --username=joe --email=joe@example.com -position_id=1` не идет. Даже если я раньше создаю эту позицию. Как создать суперпользователя?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Спасибо, что заменили картинку на код, но нужно форматировать его. Например, добавьте \`\`\` до и после кода